# Is there a way to make editor tabs stack in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs

In Visual Studio, it is possible to make the tabs for your different editor windows go over multiple lines so that you can see them all at once even when you have 20 open.

Is it possible to enable this in Visual Studio Code as well?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

On the [latest release](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_53#_wrap-tabs) of VS Code v1.53 this feature has been added

You can add `"workbench.editor.wrapTabs": true` to your json config file

Or search in the Settings UI (File > Preferences > Settings) for  Workbech > Editor: Wrap Tabs.

In adition to that you can enable shrink on tabs so they use less space (only the width of the characters) with `"workbench.editor.tabSizing": "shrink"`

Comment: Nice thing to have since Intellij IDEA seems to removing it from 2022 release (as far as i see in 2022.3 EAP)

Comment: I found a fairly satisfactory layout by setting `.tabSizing` to `fixed` and then adjust `.tabSizingFixedMinWidth`, `.tabSizingFixedMaxWidth` to  the same value (eg. 250).   Still not as pleasant as the old eclipse-style single row of tabs with an overflow dropdown, though.

Answer (score 6):

As of July 14th, 2020 there is no built-in way to make the tabs span multiple rows.

There is a discussion within the VS Code github repository about adding this feature here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70413